# Ubuntu black screen

Tags: ubuntu, laptop-display, xrandr

I have a problem with my HP G72 laptop with Intel HD Graphics integrated GPU while running any Ubuntu-based Linux distro. It always boots with a black screen (if booting without nomodeset option). I realised that the laptop screen works only if I plug in a VGA screen and type following commands in terminal:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1440x900
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900
```

But still, it works only if VGA screen is plugged. After that I can unplug the VGA screen and the laptop screen works until next reboot. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common?

Comment: This happens on every fresh ubuntu installation, even in the installation too. I will try this and reply asap

Answer (score 0):

The brightness level was set to 0.